# Asynchronously extract title from URLs using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, url

The following code asynchronously extract title from URLs (saved in `book-urls.txt`).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import grequests

links = list()

file1 = open("book-urls.txt", "r")
Lines = file1.readlines()
for line in Lines:
    links.append(line)
file1.close()

reqs = (grequests.get(link) for link in links)
resp = grequests.map(reqs)

for r in resp:
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
        print(soup.title.string)
    except:
        pass
```

The input is:

```
https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/a-reviewers-handbook/9781118025635/
https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/accounting-all-in-one-for/9781119453895/
https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/business-valuation-for/9780470344019/
https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/the-business-of/9780470444481/
```

The output is:

```
A Reviewer's Handbook to Business Valuation: Practical Guidance to the Use and Abuse of a Business Appraisal [Book]
Accounting All-in-One For Dummies, with Online Practice, 2nd Edition [Book]
Business Valuation For Dummies [Book]
The Business of Value Investing: Six Essential Elements to Buying Companies Like Warren Buffett [Book]
```

Is `grequests` the best option or should I use something else?

Please give some suggestion on how I can make this code better.

Comment: The second paragraph of the [grequests README](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests) advises you select a different tool. That's usually a pretty strong indicator.